# get label text from page load using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm using this function

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function readwebconfig() {
        var sessiontime = "<%= Session.Timeout %>";
        alert(sessiontime);
    }
</script>
```

Now, i want to assign this `sessiontime` value to label text, how can i do that.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
document.getElementById("lblmsg").innerHTML = sessiontime;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   function readwebconfig() {
   var sessiontime = "<%= Session.Timeout %>";
   document.getElementById("lblmsg").value = sessiontime;
   alert(sessiontime);
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function readwebconfig() {
        var sessiontime = "<%= Session.Timeout %>";
        document.getElementById('<%= lblmsg.ClientID%>').innerHTML=sessiontime;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like that :

```
function readwebconfig() {
        var sessiontime = "<%= Session.Timeout %>";
        document.getElementById('lblmsg').innerHTML = sessiontime;
    }
```